# Python Function That Returns "Hello" + Input + "!" Except For Two Specific Cases

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement

I'm trying to create a Python function that returns a polite greeting for everyone except for Lewis and Clark. Here is what I tried:

```
def politeGreeting(name):
    #if the user's name is Lewis or Clark, say "Oh, it's you." 
    if name == "Lewis" or "Clark":
        return("Oh, it's you")
    #if the user's name is anything else
    else:
        return("Hello," + name + "!")

name = input("please enter your name")        
print (politeGreeting(name))
```

Right now, this is printing `Oh, it's you` for everyone, not just for Lewis and Clark. I don't understand why - my IDE isn't returning any error messages. Please help if you can, thank you.

Comment: You must restate the condition for every condition! `if name == "Lewis" or name == "Clark":`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should fix your problem of not restating the condition `==` for each comparison. `Lewis` or `Clark`:

```
def politeGreeting(name):
  #if the user's name is Lewis or Clark, say "Oh, it's you." 
  if name == "Lewis" or name == "Clark":
    return("Oh, it's you")
  #if the user's name is anything else
  else:
    return("Hello, " + name + "!")

name = input("Please enter your name:")        
print(politeGreeting(name))
```

However if you want to allow for different capitalizations of input try something like this which uses [str.lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) and [str.title()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title):

```
def politeGreeting(name):
  #if the user's name is Lewis or Clark, say "Oh, it's you." 
  if name.lower() in {"lewis", "clark"}: # Use set for O(1) lookup time
    return("Oh, it's you " + name.title())
  #if the user's name is anything else
  else:
    return("Hello, " + name.title() + "!")

name = input("Please enter your name:")        
print(politeGreeting(name))
```

Comment: You should describe what the problem is in the original code as well as providing the solution

Comment: @shash678 Made sense after realizing I needed to restate the condition. Also good to know how to answer for different capitalization cases. Thanks for the link to repl.it - really cool compiler / IDE!

Answer (score 0):

The expression `name == "Lewis" or "Clarke"` will always evaluate to True. Use `name in ("Lewis", "Clarke")` instead.

```
def politeGreeting(name):
    #if the user's name is Lewis or Clark, say "Oh, it's you." 
    if name in ("Lewis", "Clark"):
        return("Oh, it's you")
    #if the user's name is anything else
    else:
        return("Hello," + name + "!")

    name = input("please enter your name")        
    print (politeGreeting(name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def politeGreeting(name):
    #if the user's name is Lewis or Clark, say "Oh, it's you." 
    if if name == "Lewis" or name == "Clark":
        return("Oh, it's you")
    #if the user's name is anything else
    else:
        return("Hello," + name + "!")

name = input("please enter your name")        
print (politeGreeting(name))
```